# Exercise on Measure theory: Zero measure plateau of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f \in C(M)$ where $M$ is a compact manifold in $\mathbb R^2$ and assume that for all $c\in \mathbb R$ the measure of the plateau of $f$ is zero, that is $\vert \{x\in M: \;f=c\} \vert=0$

> Show that there exists a function $g$ satisfying:
>
> - $g:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb R_{+}$
> - $\lim_{x\to 0^+} g(x)=0$
>
> such that, $\vert \{c-\epsilon \le f \le c+\epsilon \}\vert \le
>  g(\epsilon)$ uniform for all $c\in \mathbb R$ and $\forall \epsilon
>  >0$

**MY ATTEMPT:**

Assume $F_n:=\chi_{\{c-1/n \le f \le c+1/n \}}$ where $\chi$ denotes the characteristic function of these sets. Then $\int_M F_n\; < \infty$ since $M$ is compact and what is more, $\chi_{\{c-1/n \le f \le c+1/n \}}\to \chi_{\{f=c\}}$ due to the continuity of $f$ Hence by Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem we obtain that $\vert \{c-1/n \le f \le c+1/n \}\vert \to 0$

Although I feel close to the proof, at the end I deviate.

Any help or hint would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suppose that for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $c_n\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\delta < \big|\big\{c_n-\frac{1}{n}\leq f\leq c_n+\frac{1}{n}\big\}\big|$$
for some $\delta>0$. Since $\{c_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of elements of a compact set $f(M)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. We may assume that 
$$c = \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}c_n$$
Then maybe you can prove that 
$$\frac{\delta}{2} < \big|\big\{c-\frac{1}{n}\leq f\leq c+\frac{1}{n}\big\}\big|$$
and this would be a contradiction.

Comment: @Slup that's nice! thank you!!

Comment: If you understand the question now, feel free to write your own answer and accept it. That is the preferred way to resolve questions of this nature.

Comment: @Slup I'm sorry but looking at it again I think I don't really understand your claim. I don't see neither why the last estimate follows nor why the desired function $g$ will be independent of $c$ Could you explain it a bit more? Thanks a lot

Comment: @kaithkolesidou I added answer. Let me know if you find it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Fix $\delta>0$ and suppose that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $c_n\in f(M)$ such that 
$$\delta < \left|f^{-1}\left(\left[c_n-\frac{1}{n},c_n+\frac{1}{n}\right]\right)\right|$$
Since $M$ is compact, we may assume that the sequence $\{c_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of elements of $f(M)$ is convergent to some $c\in f(M)$. Now fix $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then there exists $m_n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\left[c_{m_n}-\frac{1}{m_n},c_{m_n}+\frac{1}{m_n}\right]\subseteq \left[c-\frac{1}{n},c+\frac{1}{n}\right]$$
Thus
$$\delta < \left|f^{-1}\left(\left[c_{m_n}-\frac{1}{m_n},c_{m_n}+\frac{1}{m_n}\right]\right)\right| \leq \left|f^{-1}\left(\left[c-\frac{1}{n},c+\frac{1}{n}\right]\right)\right|$$
This is a contradiction due to the fact that $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\left|f^{-1}\left(\left[c-\frac{1}{n},c+\frac{1}{n}\right]\right)\right| = 0$ s as you explained in your question. This implies *uniformity* : for every $\delta>0$ there exists $n_{\delta}$ such that for all $n\geq n_{\delta}$ we have $\left|f^{-1}\left(\left[c-\frac{1}{n},c+\frac{1}{n}\right]\right)\right|\leq \delta$ for every $c\in f(M)$.

Now you can define $g:[0,+\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ by formula
$$g(\epsilon) = \sup_{c\in f(M)}\left|f^{-1}\left(\left[c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon\right]\right)\right|$$
Since we proved *uniformity* we deduce that $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow +0}g(\epsilon) = 0$